# json output for muliple files

Tags: php, json

I am using this php code which works flawless for one file but when I upload multiple files generated json contains error.

```
$response = array('file' => ''.$file.'', 'date' => ''.date("d:m:y").'', 'save' => ''.$saving.'%');

echo json_encode($response);
```

If I am using one file the json output is valid

```
{"file":"http:\/\/xyy.com\/3\/4\/23968281479202046440249.png","date":"15:11:16","save"
:"<br>Original Size:8.3 Kb, &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Compressed Size:2.9Kb, &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Saving:65%"}
```

but if I am using two or more files json output is invalid and contains error.

```
{"file":"http:\/\/xxxxxxx.com\/4\/352118314792022053319009.png","date":"15:11:16","save"
:"Saving:68%"}{"file":"http:\/\/way2enjoy.com\/pdf\/1\/2\/3\/4\/270182314792022054204908.png","date":"15:11:16"
,"save":"Saving:65%"}
```

Any help will be great to make it work for multiple files.

Comment: Show us the case with two files, how the `$response` variable looks like? You should join the arrays before encoding and printing

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov http://way2enjoy.com/compress-png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string with two file objects looks like a couple of JSON objects printed one after another. You should join the arrays before encoding and printing them in order to produce a valid JSON object, e.g.:

```
$date = date("d:m:y");
$response = [
  ['file' => $file1, 'date' => $date, 'save' => $saving.'%'],
  ['file' => $file2, 'date' => $date, 'save' => $saving.'%'],
];
// Also, use the correct MIME type for JSON content
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Otherwise, make separate HTTP requests for each file.

Comment: these are coming from foreach loop. we cant make separate file name

Comment: @Steeve, of course it is possible to make different arrays for different files. You haven't posted your code, so I can't help you with this part.

Comment: here is code 
    foreach($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name)
            {

                $file=$_FILES["file"]["name"][$key];

$response = array('file' => ''.$file.'', 'date' => ''.date("d:m:y").'', 'save' => ''.$saving.'%');

echo json_encode($response);

}

Comment: @Steeve, then replace `$response = ` with `$response []=`, and move the `echo` outside the loop. On the client side you will receive JSON array of the file objects: `[{ "file": ...}, {"file": ...}]`

Comment: i tried echo outside but did not try []. give me two minutes to check, thx for ur help

Comment: @Steeve, https://gist.github.com/39befbd39ebce0cd1d185479c1b36054 . Don't trust IDEs as to your best friend. Some 8 years ago I have switched to Vim because of numerous glitches in different IDEs.

Comment: you were right. your idea worked.did exactly what you said.$response []  and echo outside for loop. now i am getting valid json for multiple files. but seems javascript id giving undefined issue,i am looking into that. thanks and sorry for delay in accepting answer. this is the link i am testing. thxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx               http://way2enjoy.com/modules/compress-png/compress-png1.php